# MySQL Query in PHP - Not Correct?

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong with this query? It appears to be correct to me:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE culture SET cult_desc=$culture WHERE cult_id is $UID");
```

Modified it, NetBeans is still giving me an error. Here's my total code for the page:

```
$culture = $_POST["culture"];
if (isset($_POST["id"]))
    $UID = $_POST["id"];
    mysql_query("UPDATE culture SET cult_desc='$culture' WHERE cult_id=$UID");
else
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO culture
             VALUES(cult_desc='$culture')");
```

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong?

Comment: because there obviously was something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the newly edited code, your update-statement is now correct, but your insert statement now is wrong.

Try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO culture (culture_desc)
             VALUES ('$culture')");
```

Answer (score 2):

what's the value of $culture?
If it's a string, you'll need to encapsulate it with quotes.

Same thing for $UID.

Also, The 'is' in the where-condition should be '='

Also: watch our with this code. Make sure that $culture and $UID can not contain any malicious values (e.g. malicious input from users)

Comment: This is an internal admin system, so there won't be malicious values.

Answer (score 2):

cult_desc probably string so need to wrap with **' '**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE culture SET cult_desc='$culture' WHERE cult_id = $UID");
```

Answer (score 1):

if SET cult_desc is a string then

```
mysql_query("UPDATE culture SET cult_desc='$culture' WHERE cult_id = $UID");
```

or

```
mysql_query("UPDATE culture SET cult_desc=$culture WHERE cult_id = $UID")
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem in the { and } of if else statement

```
$culture = $_POST["culture"];
if (isset($_POST["id"])){
    $UID = $_POST["id"];
    mysql_query("UPDATE culture SET cult_desc='$culture' WHERE cult_id=$UID");
}else{
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO culture
             VALUES(cult_desc='$culture')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE 'culture' SET `cult_desc` = '$culture' WHERE `cult_id` = '$UID'";
```

Basically, you're using is instead of =

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data type of $culture and $UID you might be missing quotes. Cult_desc sounds like a string and thus $culture should be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check the output of mysql_error.http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.

I also usually use = instead of 'is' and also wrap all of my input data in quotation marks. eg

$sql = "UPDATE 'culture' SET `cult_desc` = '".$culture."' WHERE `cult_id` = '".$UID."'";